# How can I add a method to my class due run-time?

Tags: c#, methods, runtime, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to make a KI or something which is more like a Bot which can learn a little bit. For example I want to give him new commands. Therefor the Bot has to create new Methods due run-time so it can react on my inputs with the right Method. I wanted to know if and how it is possible to add a method into my existing class due run-time.

I have found some links already and examples like the `CodeDomProvider`, `CSharpCodeProvider` and the `DynamicMethod` but it seems like they can only create new runables (exe files) or create a preset which one can execute with new parameters.

What I need is a way to create a new Method in my existing class or a way to interact with my existing class. I was already thinking about Plugins but in my opinion it would be much work to create a plugin for each method and also not efficient am I right?

You may also know a better way then creating Methods for each command?

**Edit 1:**

With `Assembly.CreateInstane("path");` I could "clone" my running program and together with a CSharpCodeProvider I could create a new exe with these Methods. But there is a problem. When I use a Method where is no Reference to in the Class such as `using System.Windows.Forms` gives me the error:

*Line number 3, error number: CS0234, 'The type or namespace name' Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'System'. (Is an assembly reference missing?);*

That would have been my Testcode right now:

```
//The String I am going to Add through my textfield
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Assembly assem = typeof(View).Assembly;
      View v = (View ) assem.CreateInstance("Usopis");
      if (! (v == null)) {
         v.Height = 300;
         MessageBox.Show("Instantiated a {0} object whose value is '{1}'",
                           v.GetType().Name, v);
      }
      else {
         MessageBox.Show("Unable to instantiate a View object.");
      }   
   }
}
```

```
//Code which should compile my String to a exe

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    textBox2.Text = "";
    CodeDomProvider codeProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
    CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
    parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
    CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, textBox1.Text);

    if(results.Errors.Count > 0) {
        textBox2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        foreach(CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors) {
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text +
                        "Line number " + CompErr.Line +
                        ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber +
                        ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";" +
                        Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    } else {
        //Successful Compile
        textBox2.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        textBox2.Text = "Success!";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a site for tutorial-on-demand or trolling for mentors.  It is a Q&A site for you have code you have a problem with and a concise question.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask]

Comment: You can add assemblies dynamically at runtime, you can also compile code dynamically created with something like CodeDom and run it as well. There is also many ways to make Plugins, Yes all of these can be done, though i think you might need to do some more research, as at the moment this question is too broad

Comment: @TheGeneral i will do some research and make the question more specific as far as I can. I also saw CodeDom already but as i understood it makes pretty much the same as the CSharpCodeProvider. So the only things i have found were to make new Classes but then I would need Pipelines to communicate. I was also thinking about plugins but then i would need a plugin for every command or not?

Comment: Well, basically you create a CodeDom and provide it to e.g. a `CSharpProvider`. However it´s up to you what you put into that DOM, you can for example put an assignment or an if-statement and put that into the DOM. However I agree TheGeneral, it´s far too broad.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp if it was not meant unkind then I am very sorry. But I don`t get why one would need a Tutorial for this. A small example or something would be enough. Creating a method due runtime cant be a that big problem or is it?

Comment: @HimBromBeere So when all of you think that the them is to big where can I get these information's then? I mean a link where I could find something would be enough for me.

Comment: @AtLeastVision What Nyssa is saying, is that your question is off topic for this website, they were not being negative at all. Your question is just too broad to fit into the format we require for Stack Overflow. You're probably better off finding a different site for these kinds of questions, there's some really good subreddits for example.

Comment: @TheGeneral so I have found something out. With `Assembly.CreateInstane("path");` I could "clone" my running program and together with a CSharpCodeProvider I could create a new exe with these Methods. But here is my problem. When I create a new exe with this i get an error cause of `using System.Windows.Forms;` which says something like 
"Line number 3, error number: CS0234, 'The type or namespace name' Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'System'. (Is an assembly reference missing?);" How could i solve this

Comment: @DavidG ok but I still do not realy get why that question is so board :O

Comment: It is too broad because we have no idea what you are stuck on.  It reads like one of those "I have no idea where to start" posts.  We cannot answer those without posting an entire tutorial  which is not what the site is intended for, and not something most people are going to spend the time composing.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp Okay, that may be kind of true but that`s why I clarified it now. I think it should be more clear what I want.

Comment: Where do you want to put your code? In a DLL in some kind of removable storage? Do you just want to read source and compile/interpret it on the fly (if so, consider a scripting language designed for that) If it were me, I'd create one or more interfaces as attachment points and then build a small plug-in architecture that allowed me to drop my compiled code in the right place and have it be loaded. You may actually find that building all your commands that way may be the way to go

Comment: @Flydog57 I am using the yml format to save data right now. What I would do is to save a the code as String and create a Method from this. It would say something like "Bot execute new Method when I say 'Open Stackoverflow' " then the Bot opens a Textfield where oen can write the Method. Therefore I would create a mini API so everyone with a little bit of codeing knowledge could create new methods. But I want to give that Code the possibility to  interact with my existing code but without makeing a pipeline for every Method. So it should just extend a existing class with a partial class

Answer (score 0):

To fix the missing namespace error you have to add the missing reference:

```
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Web.dll");
```

But that won`t solve all of your problems.
Maybe look into Lamdas...
That could be something for you:
https://www.strathweb.com/2018/01/easy-way-to-create-a-c-lambda-expression-from-a-string-with-roslyn/

Comment: Thank you very much. I will have a look on it.